# IIS WebDeploy: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

The web deployment over VS2012 with 'Publish Web' and method 'Web Deploy' failed on the target server (Win2008R2) with the **error**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4253,5): 
 Error ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED: Web deployment task failed.
```

What I did:

- deploy package by hand on the IIS -> succuessfully
- checked [this](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED) everything as it should
- [Configuring](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-%28web-deploy-handler%29) a Web Server for Web Deploy Publishing (Web Deploy Handler):
- create local user 'BuildServer' on the target server and add it into the Administrators and MSDepSvcUsers group
- create: .PublishSettings for the site with Deploy/Configure Web Deploy Publishing...

  `publishUrl="https://SAIGON-CLXBLEND:8172/msdeploy.axd"<br/>
  msdeploySite="ClxBlend (180)"<br/>
  destinationAppUrl="http://saigon-clxblend:180/"<br/>
  mySQLDBConnectionString=""<br/>
  SQLServerDBConnectionString=""<br/>
  profileName="Default Settings"<br/>
  publishMethod="MSDeploy"<br/>
  userName="SAIGON-CLXBLEND\BuildServer"<br/>`
- config Publish Web in VS:

  `Server="https://SAIGON-CLXBLEND:8172/msdeploy.axd"<br/>
  Sitename=ClxBlend (180)<br/>
  Username=SAIGON-CLXBLEND\BuildServer<br/>
  Destination URL="http://saigon-clxblend:180"/<br/>`
- restart after configuration IIS and VS
- Validate connection in Publish Web -> succuessfully
- output from IIS log:

  `C:\inetpub\logs\wmsvc\W3SVC1<br/>
  2014-04-02 11:46:39 10.1.20.13 HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=ClxBlend%20(180) 8172 SAIGON-CLXBLEND\BuildServer 10.1.20.1 - 200 0 0 12966<br/>
  2014-04-02 11:46:39 10.1.20.13 HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=ClxBlend%20(180) 8172 SAIGON-CLXBLEND\BuildServer 10.1.20.1 - 200 0 0 14<br/>
  2014-04-02 11:46:40 10.1.20.13 POST /msdeploy.axd site=ClxBlend%20(180) 8172 SAIGON-CLXBLEND\BuildServer 10.1.20.1 Unknown;sid=4cd19062-7e09-4ba8-a047-f0338161ac9f;op=Sync 200 0 0 1167<br/>
  2014-04-02 11:46:40 10.1.20.13 POST /msdeploy.axd site=ClxBlend%20(180) 8172 SAIGON-CLXBLEND\BuildServer 10.1.20.1 - 200 0 0 1376<br/>
  2014-04-02 11:49:41 10.1.20.13 HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=ClxBlend%20(180) 8172 - 10.1.20.1 - 401 2 5 292`

What's going wrong here?

Comment: The IIS in the target server uses **Shared Configuration**?